# Найти количество шагов при складывание цифры числа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Найти количество шагов при складывание цифры числа, до тех пор пока не получится однозначное значение
Например, в случае x = 5, k = 0. А в случае х = 91, к = 2. Другими словами, на первом шаге мы получим 10, на втором шаге 1.
Напишите функцию решения, которая возвращает количество шагов при складывание цифры числа, до тех пор пока не получится однозначное значение для данного числа x.

**Мой код**

```
function solution(x){
var s = 0,k = 0
x = x.toString()
if ((x<10 && x>=0) || (x>-10 && x<0)) {
    return 0
}
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    s += +x[i]
    k++
    if (x[i]==0) {
        k--
    }
}
    return s<10?k:solution(s)
}

console.log(solution(5)) // 0 // я получил 0
console.log(solution(91)) // 2 // я получил 1
console.log(solution(100)) // 1 // я получил 1
console.log(solution(99)) // 2 // я получил 2
console.log(solution(-5)) // 0 // я получил 0
console.log(solution(0)) // 0 // я получил 0
console.log(solution(9)) // 0 // я получил 0
console.log(solution(999)) // 2 // я получил 2
console.log(solution(1000)) // 1 // я получил 1
console.log(solution(9999)) // 2 // я получил 2
```

Comment: зачем вы усложняете код рассматривая отрицательные значения? на крайний случай просто избавьтесь от минуса сразу в начале функции, не надо никак это учитывать далее в коде

Comment: Сравнивайте -568 и 568 и будет ясно почему я не избавляюсь от минуса

Comment: у в моем представлении сумма цифр в -568 такая же как в 568, вы готовы это оспорить?

Comment: также не ясно, зачем вы вот эти движения `k++/k--` делаете. Вам надо просто считать сумму. не важно попадется вам там ноль или нет. Просто идти по числу и считать сумму. получите сумму меньше 10 вернете 1, больше 10 то вернете `1 + solution(sum)`

Comment: -568  = -5 + 6 + 8 = 9 // количество шагов 1
568 = 5 + 6 + 8 = 1 + 9 = 1 + 0 = 1 // количество шагов 3

Comment: ах вот этот момент return s<10?1:1 + solution(s) слишком сильный получился,спасибо Вам огромное

Comment: @ROBBSTARK, так ведь нет _цифры_  `-5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

раз уж написал вариант, то пусть остается. Рекурсия ваша должна возвращать число шагов иными словами - глубину этой самой рекурсии, то есть `1 + рекурсивный вызов`

```js
function solution(x){
   if(Math.abs(x) < 10) return 0;
   
   let nums = Math.abs(x).toString().split('').map(v => +v);
   if(x < 0) nums[0] = -nums[0];   
   let sum = nums.reduce((acc,v) => acc+v,  0);   
   
   return 1 + solution(sum);
}

const input = [5,91,100,99,-5,0,9,999,1000,9999];
input.forEach(v => console.log(v, solution(v)));
```

в целом, конечно, для решения данной задачи рекурсия не нужна. Надо в цикле складывать цифры в сумму пока она не станет меньшей 10, и вернуть число итераций этого цикла.

Answer (score 0):

День добрый!

```js
'use strict';

function solution(x){
 if ((x<10 && x>=0) || (x>-10 && x<0)) {
     return 0
 }
 x = x.toString()
 let s = 0;
 let k = 0;
 while (true) {
  k++;
  x.split('').forEach( item => s += +item );
  if (s.toString().length == 1) break;
  x = s.toString();
  s = 0;
 }
 return k;
}

console.log(solution(5)) // 0 // я получил 0
console.log(solution(91)) // 2 // я получил 1
console.log(solution(100)) // 1 // я получил 1
console.log(solution(99)) // 2 // я получил 2
console.log(solution(-5)) // 0 // я получил 0
console.log(solution(0)) // 0 // я получил 0
console.log(solution(9)) // 0 // я получил 0
console.log(solution(999)) // 2 // я получил 2
console.log(solution(1000)) // 1 // я получил 1
console.log(solution(9999)) // 2 // я получил 2
```